# Visual Studio 2017 warning says exception is caught by a base class, but it is not

Tags: c++, inheritance, exception

I started learning about exceptions in C++ and started messing with them in VS17. What i found out is that the catch of base class is going to catch the object of derived class **only** if derived class is publicly derived. Still VS gives me a warning: *1> warning C4286: 'B': is caught by base class ('A')* and this is confusing me because the program seems to work fine. Is there an explanation for this or am i missing something crucial?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


class A {
protected:
    int d;
public:
    A(int h = 3) :d(h) { cout << "Constructor A" << endl; }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a) {
        os << "Caught A " << endl;
        return os;
    }
};
//Private inheritance
class B : A {
    int e;
public:
    B(int i = 8) : e(i) { cout << "Constructor B " << e << d << endl; }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const B& b) {
        os << "Caught B" << endl;
        return os;
    }
};


double find_root(int f) {
    if (f <= 0) throw B(7);
    return sqrt(f);
}

int main() {

    try {

        try {
            cout << find_root(-1) << endl;
        }

        catch (B b) { cout << "Exception in inside Block" << endl; throw; }

    }

    catch (int) {
        cout << "Number smaller than 0" << endl;
    }

    catch (A a) {
        cout << a;
    }

    catch (B b) {
        cout << b;
    }

    int g; cin >> g;
}
```

Comment: For info: The same warning is issued by VS-2019.

Comment: This doesn't get tested often enough, private inheritance is not common.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know about it.

Comment: "does nothing here" -- please remove these parts of your code before posting here, so you get a [mcve]. It also helps you focus on the problem, sometimes making the solution obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably, this is an issue with Visual Studio 2017. I have compiled your code with gcc 9.x and it seems that gcc can give you the right warning based on public or private inheritance. Check the code online [here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8-QJbw).

Comment: I am specifically using it because tests in our uni are done in it, but i will check others as well.

Answer (score 1):

When "catching" use a [reference or const reference](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#e15-catch-exceptions-from-a-hierarchy-by-reference). What your code actually does is construct a new "A" or "B" from the exception you threw. This doesn't explain your issue, but it is making it more complex to diagnose.
If you are using Visual Studio, you can enable [static-analysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-for-c-cpp-overview?view=vs-2019). Instructions can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/quick-start-code-analysis-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2019). This might give more information and doing so will improve your coding style very quickly.
Good luck in your studies...

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, i will definitely take a look at this. The thing is i am writing code to be like the examples that come at the test. We even have questions asking us if error will come up during translation or during execution so i am going to stick with regular settings at least for now

Comment: No problem, did you check this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4286?view=vs-2019.

Comment: I didnt but it looks like a real gem. Thanks, that looks very clean and understandable.